# Ignore nil values and unwrap optionals returning the value as the wrapped type

Tags: generics, swift, null, reactive-cocoa

My primary concern is that this has been written as a global function.  I think it would be better if this was a function of the `SignalProducer` class [but I am not sure that is even possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563161/how-can-i-write-a-function-that-will-unwrap-a-generic-property-in-swift-assuming).  Is this thinking justified or is the use of global functions acceptable?

(The following code uses ReactiveCocoa 4 and is written in Swift.)

```
func ignoreNilValues <Value,Error> (producer: SignalProducer<Value?,Error>) -> SignalProducer<Value, Error> {
    return producer.filter { return $0 != nil }.map { $0! }
}
```

Comment: It turns out [it is feasible](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34575096/1721611) but requires extending the Optional enum.
I am not sure if that is a good idea either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding out that it was feasible I rewrote the global function as follows.

```
protocol AnOptional {
    typealias Wrapped
    func asOptional() -> Wrapped?
}

extension Optional : AnOptional {
    func asOptional() -> Wrapped? {
        return self
    }
}

extension SignalProducer where Value : AnOptional {
    func ignoreNilValues() -> SignalProducer<Value.Wrapped,Error> {
        return self.filter { return $0 != nil }.map { $0.asOptional()! }
    }
}
```

This is much cleaner in terms of usage but requires extending the Optional type which I am not sure would be considered best practice.

For the specific case of ignoring nil values sent from a signal it turns out there is a much simpler way, which unfortunately I missed until now.

```
let producer: SignalProducer<SomeValueType?,SomeErrorType>
let producerNoNil: SignalProducer<SomeValueType,SomeErrorType> = producer.ignoreNil()
```

Incidentally the implementation of `ignoreNil` seems to use the approach mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

There is already a function in reactiveSwift that you can use:

```
 .skipNil()
```

Comment: As mentioned in my original answer, I ended finding ignoreNil() but the question is looking for a general swift approach not only one specific reactivecocoa/swift.